# calling an activity and/or service from launcher

Tags: android

im having problem calling a new activity or service using a button from this java file and how can i make the button just a picture without background  and i always get this one "No activity specified! Getting the launcher activity." new programmer here sorry thank you

```
package com.bpi.gears;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DashboardListing extends Activity {

public static ImageButton bot4;
public static Intent activity_profile;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard_listing);

    bot4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bot4);
     Intent activity_profileintent = new          
               Intent(DashboardListing.this,activity_profile.class);
     bot4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(activity_profile);
            }});
        }
}
```

to this one

```
package com.bpi.gears;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class activity_profile extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why are you making your variables static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your startActivity() you should be passing "activity_profileintent" instead of activity_profile.
Something like this:

```
startActivity(activity_profileintent);
```

Comment: thanks prati i was able to make it work with above code thank you so much for your effort i hope you will help me again

Answer (score 0):

Try this rather than the way you're doing it

```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thank you neil it help alot...although from my log in he skipped the currentactivityactivity where i suppose to put the button it went directly to the destinationactivity i think i can make it work but thanks you for your help

Comment: My pleasure. Just a note, try and define as little static global variables as possible, except if its completely necessary. Try and reduce the scope of your variables to only where you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @SuppressWarnings("unused") from your activity. And register your destination activity into manifest. Do not use static variables for intent.